# Remove dynamically added checkboxes and corresponding images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which opens a file selector window. When the user selects a file, the script uploads that image to a div with a checkbox.

This is the part of the script that removes the checkbox and image, but it is currently removing the parent element as well.

```
$("#imageForm").on('click', 'input[value="Delete"]', function () {
    $('#iso_preview').has('input:checkbox:checked').remove()
});
```

How can I remove all checked checkboxes and their corresponding images when the delete button is clicked?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnf0bht7/3/)**

Comment: Your fiddle code actually works-ish - you just need to change `.remove()` to `.empty()` or that container `div` goes away and there's nowhere for any new uploads to go.  http://jsfiddle.net/xnf0bht7/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your insert `fileUpload()` function so that the image is contained within the inner wrapper. Change the following lines

```
if (imageType.test(file.type)) { 
    fileTemp = document.createElement("img");      
    $("#iso_preview").append("<div class='ct'><input  value='remove'type='checkbox'/></div>");
    fileTemp.classList.add("preview_image");      
} else{
    fileTemp = document.createElement('div');
    fileTemp.classList.add('div');
}     
fileTemp.file = file;

$('#'+preview).append(fileTemp);
```

To this...

```
var container = $("<div class='ct'><input  value='remove'type='checkbox'/></div>");
if (imageType.test(file.type)) { 
    fileTemp = document.createElement("img"); 
    fileTemp.classList.add("preview_image");      
} else{
    fileTemp = document.createElement('div');
    fileTemp.classList.add('div');
}     
fileTemp.file = file;
container.append(fileTemp);
$("#iso_preview").append(container);
```

Then you need to make a slight modification in this line

```
$('#iso_preview').has('input:checkbox:checked').remove();
```

To select `#iso_preview div` instead of `#iso_preview`

```
$('#iso_preview div').has('input:checkbox:checked').remove();
```

This will remove any `div` elements containing a checked checkbox that is contained within `#iso_preview`

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/xnf0bht7/8/))